# How to reverse coordinates? [react-leaflet]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, polygon, react-leaflet

> I'm trying to draw a polygon in an area in Brazil, but it's drawing in the sea, how do I reverse these coordinates?
> I'm trying to draw a polygon in an area in Brazil, but it's drawing in the sea, how do I reverse these coordinates? Follow the code above, I'm using an arrayn of coordinates, but I will soon mock this data.

```
import { LatLngExpression } from "leaflet";
import { MapContainer, Marker, Polygon, Popup, TileLayer } from "react-leaflet";
import "./App.css";

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const purpleOptions = { color: "purple" };

  const polygon: LatLngExpression[] = [
    [-59.019286, -17.461451],
    [-52.197749, -17.461451],
    [-52.197749, -12.684053],
    [-59.019286, -12.684053],
  ];


  return (
    <MapContainer
      center={[-54.125496427, -15.289267763]}
      zoom={3}
      scrollWheelZoom={true}
    >
      <TileLayer
        attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
      />
      <Marker position={[-54.125496427, -15.289267763]}>
        <Popup>
          A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
        </Popup>
      </Marker>
      <Polygon pathOptions={purpleOptions} positions={polygon} />
    </MapContainer>
  );
};

export default App;
```

[ReactLeaflet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnBqO.png)

Comment: What should the array of coords look like? "Reverse" could mean a couple of things: the values in each nested array should be swapped, or the order of the whole array should be reversed.

Comment: I can't change it because this data later came from the back end, in other map apis the drawing is correct, in the leaflet this error is occurring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this you can reverse your coordinates:

```
 polygon.map((item)=>{
    item.reverse()
 })
```

Comment: any
Property 'reverse' does not exist on type 'LatLngExpression'.
     The 'reverse' property does not exist on the 'LatLng' type.

Comment: Try `LatLngExpression[][]` instead @GHCouto (a guess). Or `[number, number][]`.

Comment: Type 'number' cannot be assigned to type 'LatLngExpression'.
It ends up giving an error in the coordinates

Comment: it worked, haha
thanks man, much appreciated!

  const polygon: [number, number][] = [
    [-59.019286, -17.461451],
    [-52.197749, -17.461451],
    [-52.197749, -12.684053],
    [-59.019286, -12.684053],
  ];
  polygon.map((item) => {
    item.reverse();
  });

Comment: I am glad it works for you